# How to display mysql table data on wordpress using $wpdb?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM student");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $results )) { 
  echo $row['id'];
  echo  $row['name'];
}
?>
```

I simply want to display id and name column values.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` not use in wordpress because  `get_results` function already fetch record

```
foreach($results as $results1)
    {
      echo $results1->id;
      echo $results1->name;
    }
```

Comment: nothing is shown in result,do i need to specify database name to $wpdb  variable?

Comment: you create student table in database??

Comment: give me file location

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM student");
foreach ( $results as $result ) { 
  echo $result->id;
  echo  $result->name;
}
```

Comment: what'is $row var ? it should be $result

Answer (score 0):

Just show the results after `get_results` , no need to mysql_`fetch`_array

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM student");
foreach($results as $res)
      echo $res->id;
      echo $res->name;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
//Fetch results as associative array
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM student", ARRAY_A);
//Cycle
for ($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
//Display them
echo $results[$i]['id'];
echo $results[$i]['name'];
}
?>
```

See the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for details.